# CSS hover image show div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have tried to add `+` but div `.shopbar_image_over` doesn't show.

```css
.shopbar_image_container img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.shopbar_image_over {
  display: none;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: #444;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.shopbar_image_container img:hover + .shopbar_image_over {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopbar_image_container">
  <div class="shopbar_image_over"></div>
  <img src="img/t.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: `+` works on the adjacent next sibling in the DOM and not the previous one. You have to modify your HTML or use other ways.

Comment: You can't travel back up the DOM tree with CSS unfortunately (compare it to regex, in some sort of way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjacent Sibling Selector (`+`) works on the adjacent next sibling in the DOM and not the previous one. In this case the `div` that you are wanting to show while hovering on the `img` is above or prior to the `img` in the DOM and hence the `+` selector will not work.

You have to either modify your HTML like in the below snippet or use alternate methods (involving JS).

```css
.shopbar_image_container img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative; /* added for positioning relative to img */
}
.shopbar_image_over {
  display: none;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px; /* added for positioning */
  cursor: pointer;
}
.shopbar_image_container img:hover + .shopbar_image_over {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopbar_image_container">
  <img src="img/t.jpg" />
  <div class="shopbar_image_over"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Option 2:** (Using JS)

Here the HTML structure is not modified, but JS is used to display the `div` when the mouse is over the `img`. Since the `div` is positioned absolutely over the `img`, the mouse out is set on the `div` and when the mouse is out, the `div` is hidden.

```js
document.getElementById("baseImage").onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById("divToShow").style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementById("divToShow").onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById("divToShow").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.shopbar_image_container img {
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.shopbar_image_over {
  display: none;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: #444;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopbar_image_container">
  <div class="shopbar_image_over" id="divToShow"></div>
  <img src="img/t.jpg" id="baseImage" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the trick is to add `position: absolute` from the `bottom` to `shopbar_image_container`,

Then add `margin-top: this.height in px` or `tramsform: translateY(this.height px)`  to be able to display `.shopbar_image_over`

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
.shopbar_image_container{
  position: relative;
  height:190px; 
  width:190px;
  margin-top: 190px
}
.shopbar_image_container img{
 height:100%;
 cursor:pointer
}


.shopbar_image_over{
 display:none;
 height:100%; 
 width:100%;
 opacity:0.2;
 background:#444;
 position:absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.shopbar_image_container img:hover + .shopbar_image_over{
 display:block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="shopbar_image_container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
  <div class="shopbar_image_over"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple example:

HTML:

```
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n03br282/

Hope its helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try working with just opacity - a bit simpler that selectors:

```css
.shopbar_image_container img{
height:190px; 
width:190px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.shopbar_image_over{
display:block;
height:190px; 
width:190px;
opacity:0;
background:#444;
position:absolute;
cursor:pointer;
}

.shopbar_image_container .shopbar_image_over:hover{
opacity:0.2; 
 }
```

```html
         <div class="shopbar_image_container">
             <div class="shopbar_image_over"></div>
          <img src="img/t.jpg" />
                               
         </div>
```